# update record in MySQL table using select statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update the last inserted record and assign to it's column  - `campaign_id` the value in `id` (same record). 
i came up with this query :

```
UPDATE campaigns
SET campaign_id= (select id order by id desc LIMIT 1)
WHERE id = (select id order by id desc LIMIT 1)
```

but for some reason i can't understand it updated the ENTIRE table, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you were intending to do:

```
UPDATE campaigns
SET campaign_id = id
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM campaigns ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Whether or not this be logically correct depends on whether the record with the max `id` is actually the latest record.  I can imagine that not being the case, but perhaps the logic in the above subquery could be changed to cover this possibility.

Comment: still update all of the records in the table...thx for the useful comment though

Comment: @yarivbar Please _edit_ your question and show us sample data and the current/expected output.  This answer seems correct to me based on the information you gave us.